# Hover Text to Change Image - Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a changing visual usage when hovering over the text in the information in the link. How can we do this using only javascript? I don't want to use jquery.

Link: https://jimfahaddigital.com/tutorial/click-text-to-change-image-using-elementor-wordpress-elementor-pro-tutorial/

jquery code used

```js
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //No Youtube Remake using this Snippet without Permission
    //Copyrighted by Jim Fahad
    var $ = jQuery
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-showme]').hover( function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')
            
            $('.all-img').hide()
            $('.' + showme).show()
            
        })
    })
    </script>
```

I don't want to use jquery. How can I do this with javascript only?

I tried various javascript methods but I was not successful.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hi actually I'm having a problem with an operation only done with jquery. I edited my post. There is a process prepared as jquery. I want to do it with javascript. I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always read the rules first, but I used to make the same mistake. It would be far better to simply Google it and try harder, and you should only come here as a last resort. Here I give you this little snippet, hope it helps.

```js
function showHide(arg) {
    let img = document.querySelector('[data-test="img"]');
    if(arg === "show"){
        img.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        img.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
showHide('hide');
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="showHide('show')" onmouseleave="showHide('hide')">
    some text
</div>
<img data-test="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLgx6.png?s=64&g=1" alt="">
```